# Evaluate $\int(2x + 9)e^{x^2+9x}dx$ using u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.3
Note: Webassign has a typo here, i messaged the guy to get him to fix it. Problem #4 should read:

Evaluate $\int(2x + 9)e^{x^2+9x}dx$ using u-substitution

Can somebody verify this for me?

---

Solution: Let $u=x^2+9x$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=2x+9$ and so $\frac{du}{2x+9}=dx$.

Thus we have:

$\int(2x + 9)e^{x^2+9x}dx$

$= \int(2x + 9)e^{u}\frac{du}{2x+9}$

$= \int e^udu$

$=e^u +C$

$=e^{x^2+9x}+C$

Comment: Looks Ok to me. I always differentiate the answer to see if I get the original problem as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me! That's the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one is custom made, since we have $f'(x)e^ {f(x)}$.  Just substitute $u=x^2+9x$, as you have done.  Since $e^x$ is its own derivative, by the chain rule everything works out.